# How to merge an object into the session based on ID using SQLAlchemy while keeping correct discriminator of child classes?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I am passing object IDs between threads, and would like to be able to merge an object into the session by ID. I could of course query objects across threads to accomplish this but would rather avoid the overhead of a database trip if the object is in the session already.

My code is working, but it is not correctly setting the discriminator value when I merge by the parent class. How can I ensure the discriminator is set correctly?

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, __version__
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker, scoped_session
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy import Column
from sqlalchemy.types import Integer, String

Session = scoped_session(sessionmaker())
Base = declarative_base()

class Person(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'person'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String, nullable=False)
    discriminator = Column(String, nullable=False)

    __mapper_args__ = {'polymorphic_identity': 'person',
                       'polymorphic_on': discriminator}

class Programmer(Person):
    __mapper_args__ = {'polymorphic_identity': 'programmer'}

    fav_language = Column(String)

engine = create_engine('postgresql+zxjdbc://mnaber:test123@localhost:5432/ajtest2', echo=True)
Session.configure(bind=engine)
Base.metadata.bind = engine


Base.metadata.drop_all(checkfirst=True)
Base.metadata.create_all()

s = Session()
michael = Programmer(name='Michael', fav_language='Python')
s.add(michael)
s.commit()


print "Sqlalchemy Version: %s" % __version__
print "INITIAL: %s %s" % (type(michael), michael.discriminator)

michael_merged = s.merge(Person(id=michael.id)) #Merge by parent class
print "MERGED: %s %s" % (type(michael_merged), michael_merged.discriminator)
print "FINAL: %s %s" % (type(michael), michael.discriminator)

michael_merged.fav_language = 'Jython'
s.add(michael_merged)
s.commit()
```

The interesting output of this is:

```
Sqlalchemy Version: 0.8.7
INITIAL: <class '__main__.Programmer'> programmer
MERGED: <class '__main__.Programmer'> person
FINAL: <class '__main__.Programmer'> person

site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/persistence.py:154: SAWarning: Flushing object <Programmer at 0x18> with incompatible polymorphic identity 'person'; the object may not refresh and/or load correctly
  mapper._validate_polymorphic_identity(mapper, state, dict_)
```

How should I ensure that MERGED and FINAL have a discriminator of programmer?

Answer (score 1):

merge() assumes an object coming in looks the way you want it to look so you'd need to pass a Programmer here.   Passing in Person(id=1) when there's really a Programmer in the database for that identity is not a supported pattern, the behavior is undefined.  What happens at the moment is that your Person object has the "discriminator" of "person" set up front, so that's the value that gets flushed into the database; it overrides what's already in the session.

You can trick it into working like this:

```
p1 = Person(id=michael.id)
del p1.discriminator
michael_merged = s.merge(p1) #Merge by parent class
```

however, I can't guarantee that code like the above will always work for future SQLAlchemy versions.  It would not, for example, work for earlier versions where the "discriminator" was chosen at flush time.

Your code example is such that Programmer is already present in the Session; you can get this object in a class-agnostic way like this:

```
obj = session.query(Person).get(michael.id)
```

then you have your Programmer object and you can modify it freely.